# Laravel flysystem ftpd adapter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, thephpleague

I want to use the ftpd Adapter in Laravel to access a Synology NAS, which seems to need this specific adapter https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/305, but I get the error

```
Driver [Ftpd] is not supported.
```

The file is there:

```
vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Ftpd.php
```

Do I have to register anything that I can use it?

I tried to use it in filesystems.php like this

```
    'diskstation' => [
        'driver'   => 'Ftpd',
        'host'     => 'ftp.domain.com',
        'username' => '****',
        'password' => '****',

        // Optional FTP Settings...
        'port'     => 21,
        'root'     => '',
        'passive'  => true,
        'ssl'      => false,
        'timeout'  => 10,
    ],
```

Comment: Try the driver lower case, `ftpd`

Comment: thanks, already tryed, not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like laravel does not support ftpd out of the box as you can see here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php#L13

It imports a few of the Flysystem drivers, but not the ftpd one.

However you can create custom drivers like is shown [here in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#custom-filesystems). The ftpd driver is already build for flysystem so you just need to import it in laravel via this method.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.. The ftpd class is already there, so I could just make a service provider and add this in the boot() method:         Storage::extend('Ftpd', function ($app, $config) {
            return new Filesystem(new Ftpd($config));
        });